# Is it possible to display text on a rich text item in a DocumentContext?

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I have a form that runs a java agent on the WebQueryOpen event. This agent pulls data from a DB2 database and then puts them into the computed text fields I have placed on the form and are displayed whenever I open the form in the browser. This is working for me. However, when I try to use RichTextFields I get a ClassCastException error. No document is actually saved, I just open the form in the browser using this domino URL - https://company.com/database.nsf/sampleform?OpenForm

Sample code of simple text field - Displayed with w/o problems

```
Document sampledoc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
String samplestr = "sample data from db2";
sampledoc.replaceItemValue("sampletextfield", samplestr);
```

When I tried using rich text field

```
Document sampledoc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
String samplestr = "sample data from db2";
RichTextItem rtsample = (RichTextItem)sampledoc.getFirstItem('samplerichtextfield');
rtsample.appendText(samplestr); // ClassCastException error
```

Basically, I wanted to use rich text field so that it could accommodate more characters in case I pull a very long string data.

Screenshot of the field (As you can see it's a RichText)

[image: Screenshot of the field (As you can see it's a RichText)]

Comment: Is samplerichtextfield an existing item that was already saved in the document, and if so do the document properties show that that item actually has the type RICH TEXT?

Comment: I guess it's not possible. I read this answer from this page

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/869c7412fe5d56b7852569fa007826e3/818a879204e315ab85256f8700775ddf?OpenDocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access a regular Item as a RichTextItem.

The RichTextItem are special fields that are created with its own method just like this:

```
RichTextItem rtsample = (RichTextItem)sampledoc.createRichTextItem('samplerichtextfield');
```

It's different to the regular Items that can be created with a simple `sampledoc.replaceItemValue(etc)`.

So, if you want to know if a item is RichTextItem and if it does not exist, create it, you can do this:

```
RichTextItem rti = null;
Item item = doc.getFirstItem("somefield");
if (item != null) {
    if (item instanceof RichTextItem) {
        //Yay!
        rti = (RichTextItem) item;
    } else {
        //:-(
    }
} else {
        rti = doc.createRichTextItem("somefield");
        //etc.
}
```

Comment: I tried however this appeared in the server logs.
11/15/2014 03:24:34 PM  HTTP JVM: searchresults not instanceof RichTextItem. I also posted a screenshot that I've set the field to RichText type

Comment: One feature of Lotus Notes is that the definition of a field _in the form_ could be RichText, BUT the field itself _in the document_ could be anything. That happen when the field is created using code (LotusScript, Java, etc.), and that's because Lotus Notes does not verify if the field's type in the form is the same as the value that you are writing. So, to verify the field's type, you need to find the document, open the same properties window, find the value and check its type. Look at [here](http://es.tinypic.com/r/2nl5vv7/8)